# How do I vertically align text in text input at React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I am new to React Native. Text in text input looks different on android and iOS. How do I vertically align text in text input?

My codes:

```js
import React from "react"
import { TextInput } from "react-native"


export default function Signup() {

    return (
        <TextInput
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 30, textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
        />
    )
}
```

Pictures:

[image]

Comment: Try alignItems: 'top'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[textAlignVertical](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalignvertical-android) is Android only.

Looks you problem may be solved with `paddingBottom: <number>`, or try setting `lineHeight` equal to `fontSize`.

Comment: paddingBottom fixed my problem. Thanks!